# Indirect question

Tags: word-order, reported-speech, indirect-objects

What's the correct between these two  sentences

> Could you please tell me what exactly are you doing ?

OR

> Could you please tell me what exactly you are doing ?

Comment: The second. You have already used the inversion *could you*. There's no need for you to invert again.

Comment: Are you sure ? My classmates said the correct form is the first one

Comment: see **[the Penthouse Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penthouse_principle)**

Comment: So the two sentences is correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither sentence is standard English.

*Can you tell me exactly what you are doing?* is the standard form.

However, *Can you tell me what exactly you are doing?* is a common variation in which the typical word order has been changed.

By changing the typical word order the speaker is being emphatic and so expressing annoyance or irritation.

Answer (score 0):

In your sentences, the transposition of **what** and **exactly** can lead to two different meanings:

> Can you tell me **exactly** what you are doing?

means can you describe **in detail** what you are doing, **the steps**

> Can you tell me **what exactly** you are doing?

Asks for details about **the goal** you are trying to achieve